# Debian not logged in with proper password after upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, login, gdm

Just after upgrade my system start to fail when I try to login as normal user both via `gdm` and `tty`. However it's not possible to login as `root` too. When try to login via tty it outputs 'Login Incorrect'. Via the `gdm` the same but another words used.
I've changed passwords with live cd but it's not helped.
I tried to check logs, but last log changed before upgrade.

How to reslolve this? 
Thanks!

PS. `chroot`ing from live cd to purpose system successfully done however.

Comment: While you shouldn't generally do this, have you tried typing the password into the username prompt, just to make sure the keyboard isn't messed up? So many times I've had keyboards flip on upgrades, turning german, swiss and even korean, making entering complicated passwords a right pain!

Comment: I checked it, the pass's symbols is correct.

Comment: What was the upgrade?  Jessie-to-Stretch, or something else?

Comment: timday, it was Update a bunch of packages with command aptget install mongodb gnome-settings-tools mutter. But because system packages was upgraded not recent , command installed more than these pakckages including system ones

Comment: Maybe there is a log ? Where it should write if login was failed or succeed?